# Как запомнить выбор языка сайта

Tags: php, cookie

Собственно знаю что нужно использовать COOKIES, но не знаю как прикрутить себе, я использую такие URL: site.com/en/, русский по умолчанию (без приставки ru). Языковые файлы подключаются автоматически в зависимости от en, ru, uk, de, by и тд. Узнать текущий язык можно так

```
App::getRouter()->getLanguage();
```

Ну и в зависимости от языка писать куку, а потом при входе пользователя проверять. Но если у него есть кука, как его перенаправить по тому же url, но на его язык?
Для того чтобы подставить нужный язык к url, например когда пользователь меняет язык и чтобы он попадал на туже страницу у меня написана такая функция

```
Lang::getLink();

// Например

<a href="http://site.com<?=Lang::getLink('en')?>"
```

в итоге если пользователь перешел со страницы: site.com/category/article
по ссылке выше то он попадает на: site.com/en/category/article

Прошу прощения если не внятно объяснил)

Comment: в сессии запиши и всё

Comment: Фреймворк какой?

Comment: @toxxxa, Самописний

Comment: @Naumov, да нету разницы сессия это или cookie, направить пользователя как?

Comment: Как вариант записывать ip и id языка в отдельную таблицу

Comment: @asd, Вы наверное не поняли, ну какая разница куда писать... Как мне потом пользователя направить на страницу? Если он к примеру выбирал английский язык, а с гугла попал на русскоязычную версию. Русскоязычная версия site.com/category/article, без ru так как язык по умолчанию, как его направить на site.com/en/category/article, при условии что мне уже известен какой язык он выбрал?

Comment: `header("Location: http://site.com/en/category/article/");exit;`

Comment: @AK, Вечный редирект будет!

Comment: @ВадимПедченко Сформулируйте, пожалуйста, вопрос тщательно - а то непонятно, толи вы не знаете про куки, толи не знаете, как в PHP редирект сделать и совсем плохо объясняете, что у вас за самописный код.

Comment: @AK Знаю и про куки и про редирект, что вам не понятно? Попробуйте выполнить то что написали это приведет к вечному редиректу!

Comment: Откуда вечный редирект? Сравните язык, записанный в куке с языком текущего подсайта: совпали - хватит редиректить. Не совпали - редирект.